# SmartGIT does not ask for ssh key

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, key, smartgit

after switching over to a new computer I had to install SmartGIT for Windows again and now try to clone my fedorahosted.org-repository. Keys are stored C:/User/myusername/.ssh, SmartGIT comes with a clean installation and URL for cloning my repository is correct - unfortunately SmartGIT does NOT ask for the key, it just tries to connect to fedorahosted.org but then of course fails.

So...what could be wrong here? Where do I have to place my ssh keys so that SmartGIT finds and uses it?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/howtos/5/show?page=config.ssh-tunnel

Comment: Also try to configure **System SSH client** in the SmartGit preferences.

Comment: @mstrap: thanks, that was the solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was facing the same problem, as Smart Git wouldn't ask me for the SSH key location when trying to clone a repo (instead, the process would just hang..).

Steps to resolve (on Windows):

1. Copy ssh keys to C:/Users/MyUserName/.ssh (as they were in a different location before after generation)
2. Clone the repository in Smart Git again, now after specifying the repository URL, it DID ask for the SSH key location (this dialog was not shown before!)
3. Select the SSH private key (which has been converted with e.g. Putty Keygen to an OpenSSH compatible format)
4. Voila, cloning works!

PS: I agree Smart Git's behavior above was weird here, as it would only let u select the key location, if the keys are in the .ssh folder specified above

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what exactly format did you use (SSH-1)?
I added .ppk files to .ssh folder, and SmartGit still doesn't ask for key

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem.
select option 'Use SmartGit as SSH client' from SmartGit -> Edit-> Preference -> Authentication 
And it worked.

Comment: I see all my (two) keys under that option as `known credentials`, a button to remove, but none to add credentials... (?)

Answer (score 0):

**0)**

- ensure [your ssh-agent is started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606760)
- ensure your keys are added: `ssh-add -l`
- otherwise: `cd ~/.ssh` resp. `cd %USERPROFILE%\.ssh`, `sshadd ./keyOne`, ...

**1)** I added a new remote in a dos box

```
git remote add origin-github git@github.com:memyselfandi/some-project.git
```

**2)** went into Smartgit Branches view and set right-click "fetch" and got...

**The SSH authentication dialog**, asking me for the right key. (which differs with me, depending on repo, not just id_rsa...)

(you may later delete that superficious branch again. Mission completed.)

Answer (score 0):

I was using password authentication for years until Github disabled it.  So in my case the solution was to edit the .git/config file and change the repo url from the https:// address to the appropriate ssh address (you can get this by using your browser to visit your repo and click the "code" button, then select ssh option.)  Restart SmartGit and try to pull/push.  After that, it asked for the private key.