# How to use different keys for different Bitbucket repos in SmartGit?

Tags: git, macos, ssh, smartgit

When using *SmartGit* as SSH-client, it caches the first selected key. And when further you trying to pull/push to another repo, SmartGit says `"Access denied"`.

SmartGit saves to preferences what key should it use to connect to the Bitbucket. But all repos has address: `ssh://git@bitbucket.org` in SmartGit preferences.

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291973/smartgit-does-not-ask-for-ssh-key) and in [this thread](http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/Support-for-ssh-config-on-Windows-td7379578.html), you should be able to [reference multiple private ssh keys in a `%HOME%\.ssh\config file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31176591/6309), changing the url to `bitbucket1:userA/myrepo1`, `bitbucket2:userA/myrepo2`.

That means that:

- you have selected System SSH in the preferences
- have added a `%HOME%\.ssh\config file` with:

config:

```
host bitbucket1
        user git
        hostname bitbucket.org
        port 22
        identityfile /C/path/to/.ssh/key1
host bitbucket2
        user git
        hostname bitbucket.org
        port 22
        identityfile /C/path/to/.ssh/key2
```

- in `/C/path/to/.ssh/`, you have a `key1` (private) and `key1.pub` (public) ssh files (same for `key2`/`key2.pub`)