# SSH KEY Already Exists Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

For the 2 multiple projects, 2 multiple bitbucket developer accounts are used but in the same machine.
SSH KEY is accepted for the one Bitbucket account.

When I add the same key to the other bit bucket accounts, It shows KEY already exists ?

**How could I avoid this problem ?
Is there a security reasons behind this ?**

It accepts the same key in Gitlab
Note: Currently we are using HTTPS connection for other accounts ?

Comment: Multiple bitbucket accounts can't have the same SSH key - the authentication is done through the key and the assumption that it's unique to one user.  Generate a second key for the other account.

Comment: @birryree You are right. But I am using the SSH key at the same machine.
Did you mean that it takes the Individual accounts as unique ?
I don't think so, because same key accepts in gitlab..

Comment: it will be better when i get a reason for the down votes. It might be the answer for someone...

Comment: What does gitlab have anything to do with this? In Bitbucket, unique users have to have their own ssh keys. Imagine this basic security problem: user A has SSH key B and access to a bunch of private repos. User C is able to add SSH key B to his own account. User C now has access to those same private repos the other user does, even if there isn't any intention for that to happen. It doesn't matter if the users access the stuff from the same machine - to Bitbucket, you still are using distinct accounts if you both have accounts.

Comment: lol again - I'm pretty sure gitlab does not accept having the same key on multiple accounts.

Comment: ok... then how come gitlab accepts the same key over there  ?

Comment: Like @griwes said, I'm pretty sure gitlab isn't allowing multiple accounts to use the same SSH key. Are you both just checking out with the same account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could I avoid this problem? Is there a security reason behind this?

Yes: if a public key is registered in a Bitbucket account, that means any git operation using that SSH URL would be associated with that account.

Registering the *same* public SSH key to a different account would mean having to choose between two Bitbucket user accounts. That is not possible.

What you can do is create a different public/private couple of SSH keys, and reference one or the other Bitbucket account, by declaring both sets of SSH keys in an `~/.ssh/config` file.

See "[How to use different keys for different Bitbucket repos in SmartGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32324506/6309)"

```
host bitbucket1
        user git
        hostname bitbucket.org
        port 22
        identityfile /C/path/to/.ssh/key1
host bitbucket2
        user git
        hostname bitbucket.org
        port 22
        identityfile /C/path/to/.ssh/key2
```

Then:

- Pushing to `bitbucket1:repoA` will use the `user1`.
- Pushing the same repo, but with `bitbucket2:repoA` will use the `user2`.

Comment: Now I understood the real reason but I am just wondering about the words **the other through an ~/.ssh/config file**  Can you please explain little bit ? And also generate a new ssh key without overriding the existing one with the new path...

Comment: @NandaKumar the complete expression is "one or the other through an `~/.ssh/config` file": meaning reference one or the other account, by declaring two different sets of ssh keys in an `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Superb. You rocks..I checked my .ssh key folder and can't able to find the config file. Do we need to create the file or it is missing in my machine ?

Comment: @NandaKumar yes, you can create one ~/.ssh/config file: see a practical example in http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/ for instance.

Comment: Nice one.. While ssh-keygen how could i change the destination path ?

Comment: @NandaKumar use the `-f` option to specify another `file` (`file.pub`) for `ssh-keygen` to use when generating new private/public keys. See for example http://serverfault.com/a/323961/783.

Comment: Why not just choose the user that has that repo+key pair? The downside of disallowing one private key identity for multiple Bitbucket accounts is that a bad actor now has a means of searching for collisions across ALL Bitbucket accounts.

Comment: @NathanFig Not sure how that would work: SSH keys are linked to user accounts rather than specific repositories. When an SSH request is made, the server first authenticates the user based on the key and then checks if the user has access to the requested repository. That two-step process is simpler and more secure than linking keys directly to repositories. Plus, in practice, SSH keys are designed to be unique and secure. The probability of two users independently generating the same SSH key pair is very (very) low.