# Unable to clone a gitolite repo created in ubuntu in windows

Tags: gitolite

I created a gitolite repo in my ubuntu server following the steps mentioned in the below link.

http://www.bigfastblog.com/gitolite-installation-step-by-step

From my ubuntu client, I was able to clone the repo, by giving necessary information in `~/.ssh/conf`

In windows I again created `.ssh/conf` similar to ubuntu, `.ssh/conf` is as shown below:

```
 Host gitbox
 User gitolite
 Hostname 10.47.52.185
 Port 22
 IdentityFile C:\Users\AY\.ssh\anish
```

Now when I try to clone, it is giving me below error:

```
 git clone gitbox:gitolite-admin
 Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitbox: no address associated with name
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

I guess  `.ssh/conf` doesn't have any effect.
How can I clone a gitolite repo in windows?

Answer (score 2):

Simple: when given an alias, ssh will look for `%HOME%/.ssg/config`.

As in "`config`", not "`conf`".

Make sure `HOME` is defined (to  `C:\Users\AY`). And that your ssh config file is named "`config`".

Also test if `ssh -i C:\Users\AY\.ssh\anish -T gitolite@10.47.52.185` does work.

In addition, the [OP anish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5275810/anish) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771467/unable-to-clone-a-gitolite-repo-created-in-ubuntu-in-windows/33772378?noredirect=1#comment55312550_33772378):

> I have used the `gitolite.pub` from ubuntu, I created `anish.pub` in windows and added this to gitolite and changed `conf/gitolite.conf` as shown below repo

```
gitolite-admin RW+ = gitolite 
repo testing 
  RW+ = @all 
repo bigfastblog 
  RW+ = anish
```

Make sure to push that gitolite.conf back to the Ubuntu server, and check that `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys` does list `anish.pub` content.
Also Windows `HOME/.ssh` should include `anish.pub` and `anish` (the private key)

The [OP anish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5275810/anish) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771467/unable-to-clone-a-gitolite-repo-created-in-ubuntu-in-windows#comment55356794_33772378):

> Finally able to clone: It is problem with `HOME` environment variable.

Comment: @anish are you on Mac? I thought you were on Windows? What HOME is set to?

Comment: Hi Vonc, I created gitolite on ubuntu server and trying to do git clone to this server from windows

Comment: @anish Then why your ssh (on Windows) is trying to modify `/home/ayl5kor/.ssh/known_hosts`? This is not a Windows path.

Comment: Sorry i have used the gitolite.pub from ubuntu, I created anish.pub in windows and added this to gitolite and changed conf/gitolite.conf as shown below 


repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   gitolite 

repo testing
    RW+     =   @all

repo bigfastblog
     RW+     = anish 
   
Now how  can i access this from windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95405/discussion-between-anish-and-vonc).

Comment: Hi VonC, after adding above data in gitolite.conf i have done git clone on my windows pc using git clone gitolite@10.47.52.185:bigfastblog.git
which is asking for a password, which i have not set

Comment: ya it is showing anish  in authorized keys gitolite start
command="/home/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell anish"

Comment: @anish That is expected. I'll get back to you in one hour: I have to commute to work first.

Comment: @anish And... back. Chat is blocked at work, so here is my comment. From Windows, you need to use `%HOME%\.ssh\config` file, and test the url gitbox: `ssh -T gitbox`: it will be translated into `ssh -T -i C:\Users\AYL5KOR\.ssh\anish -T gitolite@10.47.52.185`, which will use the public `anish.pub` and private `anish` ssh keys.

Comment: @anish If that is still not working, try also, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32778189/6309, a unix-style path for the `IdentityFile` field: `/C/Users/AYL5KOR/.ssh/anish` in your `.ssh/config` file on Windows.

Comment: Hi Vonc, Finally able to clone, It is problem with HOME enviroment variable.

Comment: @anish Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Could you consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer?